If burst time becomes 0 highestpriority must change how to do it?
Enter process 1 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 1 0 8 3
1 0 0
Enter process 2 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 2 1 2 4 1 1 0
Enter process 3 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 3 3 4 4 0 0 1
Enter process 4 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 4 4 1 5 0 1 1
Enter process 5 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 5 5 6 2 1 0 1
Enter process 6 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 6 6 5 6 0 1 0
Enter process 7 details (pid, arrival, burst, priority, color R, G, B):): 7 10 1 1 0 0 0
 void UpdatePreemptivePriority() {
     // Sort processes based on arrival time if not already sorted
     sort(processes.begin(), processes.end(), [](const Process& a, const Process& b) {
         // If arrival time is 0, prioritize it regardless of priority
         if (a.arrivalTime == 0 && b.arrivalTime != 0) {
             return true;
         }
         else if (a.arrivalTime != 0 && b.arrivalTime == 0) {
             return false;
         }
         else if (a.arrivalTime == 0 && b.arrivalTime == 0) {
             // If both arrival times are 0, compare priorities
             if (a.priority != b.priority) {
                 return a.priority < b.priority;
             }
             // If priorities are the same, compare burst times
             return a.burstTime < b.burstTime;
         }
         else {
             // If arrival times are not 0, compare based on priority
             if (a.arrivalTime != b.arrivalTime) {
                 return a.arrivalTime < b.arrivalTime;
             }
             // If priorities are the same, compare arrival times
              if (a.priority != b.priority) {
                 return a.priority < b.priority;
             }
             // If arrival times and priorities are the same, compare burst times
             return a.burstTime < b.burstTime;
         }
         });


     // Check if any process has arrived and add it to the ready queue
     // Check if any process has arrived and add it to the ready queue
     while (nextProcessIndex < processes.size()&& processes[nextProcessIndex].arrivalTime <= currentTime) {
        
             Process p = processes[nextProcessIndex];
             p.x = -200 - nextProcessIndex * 20; // Initial x position
             p.y = 100; // Initial y position
             p.radius = 10; // Radius of the process circle
             p.isExecuting = false;
             p.id = nextProcessIndex + 1; // Set process ID using index

             // Update response time if it's not set
             if (p.responseTime == 0) {
                 p.responseTime = currentTime - p.arrivalTime;
             }

             processes[nextProcessIndex] = p;
             readyQueue.push(p);
             nextProcessIndex++;
       
     }

     // Check if no process is currently executing or context switch is needed
     if (prevExecutingProcessIndex == -1 && !readyQueue.empty()) {
         Process highestPriorityProcess = readyQueue.front(); // Initialize with the first process in the queue
         int highestPriorityIndex = 0; // Index of the highest priority process
       
         vector<Process> tempVector;
         while (!readyQueue.empty()) {
             tempVector.push_back(readyQueue.front());
             readyQueue.pop();
         }

         // Iterate over the vector
         int index = 0;
         for (const auto& p : tempVector) {
             // Check if the current process has higher priority than the highest priority process found so far
             if (p.burstTime > 0 && p.priority < highestPriorityProcess.priority) {
                 highestPriorityProcess = p;
                 highestPriorityIndex = p.id-1;
             }
             else if (p.burstTime > 0 && p.priority > highestPriorityProcess.priority)
             {
                 highestPriorityProcess = p;
                 highestPriorityIndex = p.id - 1;
                 break;
             }
             index++;
         }
         for (const auto& process : tempVector) {
             readyQueue.push(process);
         }
         // Execute the highest priority process
         highestPriorityProcess.isExecuting = true;
         prevExecutingProcessIndex = highestPriorityIndex;

         // Update current time
         currentTime++;

         // Update response time if it's not set
         if (highestPriorityProcess.responseTime == 0) {
             highestPriorityProcess.responseTime = currentTime - highestPriorityProcess.arrivalTime;
         }
     }


     // Move the process towards the CPU
     if (prevExecutingProcessIndex != -1) {
         Process& p = processes[prevExecutingProcessIndex];
         float dx = cpu.x - p.x;
         float dy = cpu.y - p.y;
         float dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

         p.x += dx / dist * 1;
         p.y += dy / dist * 1;

         // Check if the process has reached the CPU
         if (p.x >= cpu.x - 20 && p.x <= cpu.x + 20 && p.y >= cpu.y - 20 && p.y <= cpu.y + 20) {
             // Execute the process for one time unit (preemptive)
             p.burstTime--;
             cout << p.burstTime << endl;
             if (p.burstTime != 0)
             {

                 ganttChart.chart.push_back({ p.pid, make_tuple(p.arrivalTime, currentTime, p.color) });
                 readyQueue.pop();
                 readyQueue.push(p);
                 p.x = -200 - prevExecutingProcessIndex * 20; // Initial x position
                 p.y = 100; // Initial y position
                 prevExecutingProcessIndex = -1;


             }
             // Update Gantt chart and remove the process if completed
             // ...

             else if (p.burstTime == 0) {

                 ganttChart.chart.push_back({ p.pid, make_tuple(p.arrivalTime, currentTime, p.color) });
                 readyQueue.pop();

                 p.turnaroundTime = currentTime - p.arrivalTime;
                 p.waitingTime = p.turnaroundTime - p.originalBurstTime;
                 // Remove the process from the processes vector
                 p.x = -200 - prevExecutingProcessIndex * 20; // Initial x position
                 p.y = 100; // Initial y position
                 prevExecutingProcessIndex = -1; // Reset the currently executing process index to allow context switching
                 cpu.color[0] = 0.0;
                 cpu.color[1] = 1.0;
                 cpu.color[2] = 0.0;
             }
         }
     }

     // Update the display
     glutPostRedisplay();
 }

i tried to sort the process based on priority ,it is sorting but if burst time becomes 0 of the highestpriorityprocess then the code fails

Please give answer for this problem
